# Customizing ArcGIS toolbox layout

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, python-toolbox, arcgis-10.7

I am trying to create a customized tool in ArcGIS using Python Toolbox. Does anyone know how I can change the appearance (for example, size of a textbox or position of a parameter) of a parameter on the tool dialog? I did some searching online and could only found this ESRI documentation: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/documenting_tools_and_toolboxes/changing_tool_dialog_appearance.htm, which does not provide much information.

In the built-in ArcGIS Spatial Analyst Tools->Interpolation->Kriging tool, the dialog looks like this:
[image: ArcGIS Kriging Tool Dialog]

How can I make my customized tool to have something like the red part in the Kriging tool dialog?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.